# Nested Ajax Calls. Loop thru id on new ajax cakk

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the instagram's api and to get the comments I must grab the id of the post and pass it into the url of the comments api and then. I am doing then by assigning the id into a data attribute and then calling it in the ajax comments function. For some reason the id's do not loop on the second ajax call, it keeps calling the same id. What am I doing wrong??

```
/********************************
             List Media
     ********************************/
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        url: urls.media,
        success: function (media) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                var iglist = media.data[i];

                var media_template =
                    '<div class="media-container" data-media-id="' + iglist.id + '">'+
                        '<div class="image-wrapper"><img width="100%" src="' + iglist.images.standard_resolution.url + '"/></div>'+
                        '<div class="comments-wrapper"></div>'+
                    '</div>';

                $('#results-container').append(media_template);


                /********************************
                             Comments
                 ********************************/
                $(iglist).each(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + iglist.id + '/comments?access_token=' + accessToken,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (comments) {

                            for(c = 0; c < 20; c++) {

                                var cdata = comments.data[c];

                                console.log(cdata);

                                var comments_template =
                                    '<li data-comment-id="' + cdata.id + '">' +
                                    '<div class="user-photo"><img src="' + cdata.from.profile_picture + '" </div>' +
                                    '<div class="user-text">' + cdata.text + '</div>' +
                                    '</li>';

                                    //$('.comments-wrapper').append(comments_template);

                            }
                        },

                        error: function (comments) {
                            //alert('No comments at this time');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        },

        error: function (data) {
            alert('No images at the time');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

iglist is not a variable not a jquery object use `$.each`

```
 /********************************
                 List Media
         ********************************/
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            cache: false,
            url: urls.media,
            success: function (media) {
                for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

                    var iglist = media.data[i];

                    var media_template =
                        '<div class="media-container" data-media-id="' + iglist.id + '">'+
                            '<div class="image-wrapper"><img width="100%" src="' + iglist.images.standard_resolution.url + '"/></div>'+
                            '<div class="comments-wrapper"></div>'+
                        '</div>';

                    $('#results-container').append(media_template);


                    /********************************
                                 Comments
                     ********************************/
                    $.each(media.data,function(index,val) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + val.id + '/comments?access_token=' + accessToken,
                            dataType: 'jsonp',
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (comments) {

                                for(c = 0; c < 20; c++) {

                                    var cdata = comments.data[c];

                                    console.log(cdata);

                                    var comments_template =
                                        '<li data-comment-id="' + cdata.id + '">' +
                                        '<div class="user-photo"><img src="' + cdata.from.profile_picture + '" </div>' +
                                        '<div class="user-text">' + cdata.text + '</div>' +
                                        '</li>';

                                        //$('.comments-wrapper').append(comments_template);

                                }
                            },

                            error: function (comments) {
                                //alert('No comments at this time');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            },

            error: function (data) {
                alert('No images at the time');
            }
```